# ClickOnce Publish Failure - library not found

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I'm having a problem publishing a WPF app.

It seems to be caused by the "Publisher" looking for the dll's (from referenced projects) in the wrong place.

I'm getting this error in the Output Window:

```
Metadata file 'C:\***\DeviceInfo\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\DeviceInfo.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\***\Helpers\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\Helpers.dll' could not be found
```

The referenced projects in question are not necessarily window projects so they are getting published to their own bin\Release\net5.0 folders.

The net5.0-windows folder is not getting generated but the Publisher is still looking for them there.

The app runs fine from Visual Studio in Debug and Release mode.

Do I have to create these folders myself and the copy and paste into them or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Are those project references?

Comment: @Zer0 Yes. Every project reference is giving me this error

Comment: Try setting CopyLocal to true?

Comment: @Zer0 where do I do that?

Comment: Go to the main project (the one you want published) - >  dependencies -> projects -> click on a project reference and CopyLocal is in designer properties.  Set it to true.

Comment: @Zer0 I don't seem to have that option in VS2019

Comment: I'm using VS2019.  You need solution explorer open.  And properties window.

Comment: @Zer0 I just did that on 2 of my project references and it created the "net5.0-windows" folder. So it seems like that will work. It's getting late here so I'll have a proper look tomorrow. What does setting CopyLocal to true do? Will it cause me issues if the projects are referenced by a different non-wpf app?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.reference.copylocal?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).  It should not cause any issues.  You're changing the settings for the main project alone.  You can open the project file in any text editor to see what's changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested here's how I solved it.
I changed

```
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
      <TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

in all the referenced projects.

I'm not sure if this was the best way to handle it but it seems to have worked.